# Type Error in findContours() function in Opencv python

Tags: python, opencv

```
for i in xrange(len(rects)):
    if abs(rects[i][2])>=0 and abs(rects[i][2])<=1:
        rect_size=rects[i][1]
        rect_size=list(rect_size)
        rect_size = np.int0(rect_size)
        img_crop=cv2.getRectSubPix(Image, tuple(rect_size), rects[i][0])    
        grayResult=cv2.cvtColor(img_crop,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        grayResult=cv2.blur(grayResult,(3,3))
        grayResult=cv2.equalizeHist(grayResult)
        cv2.imshow('GrayScale',grayResult)      
        cv2.waitKey(0)
        img_threshold,mask=cv2.threshold(grayResult, 60, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
        img_contours=img_threshold
        cont,hier=cv2.findContours(img_contours,cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
```

The `findContours()` function used in the last line is giving the following error:

```
cv2.error: /build/buildd/opencv-2.4.8+dfsg1/modules/imgproc/src/contours.cpp:196: error: (-210) [Start]FindContours support only 8uC1 and 32sC1 images in function cvStartFindContours
```

Please suggest a way to remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you pass a `B,G,R` image or ... to `findContours` , but [`findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) function retrieves contours from the binary image .
this is a example that convert the raw image to binary with `cv2.adaptiveThreshold`

```
im = cv2.imread('nnn.png') 
gray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray,(5,5),0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(blur,255,1,1,11,2)

contours,hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh,cv2.RETR_LIST,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```